# Using string based variables in knockouts controlflow templates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using Knockout's containerless controlflow templates:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myData" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: url}" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{url}}" />
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Getting the url into the href is working, but I want to call the url value again in the image src. I want to keep the beginning part of the image source and just add the url to the end. How would one do this using a Knockout template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple task you don't need any additional templating because KO lets you write any arbitrary expression in your bindings like string concatenation.

So you can just build your url right in the `attr` binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myData" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {href: url}" target="_blank">
            <img data-bind="attr: { 
                 src: 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + url()}" />
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: you need to write `url()` if your `url` property is a `ko.observable` to get its value inside the binding expression.

However a more proper solution would be to calculate the image url inside the view model and you would have a `imageUrl` property which you would bind with `<img data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }"/>`